# Subscibe to specific device with AWS or Azure IoT services

Tags: aws-iot, aws, azure

There are 1,000 IoT devices which need to send data to the cloud each second. There is a mobile app. The mobile app user can see messages from a single device at a time only. Is there any simple (built in) way to achieve such subscription to single IoT device using Azure? I was trying to find the way to do this with Event Hubs and IoT Hub, but failed.

I found AWS has something called [Message Broker for AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-message-broker.html). Is it what I need? I would still prefer to use Azure, but I suspect that I have to use tons of their other services, which increase both complexity and the cost of solution.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't worked with Azure as such but Message Broker for AWS IoT uses MQTT and is like any other MQTT broker (like mosquitto for Linux).

MQTT messages basically work on Topics. If the android app is subscribing to a topic then it can receive messages for that topic.

Suppose if you have two IoT devices sending data op topics "Topic/Dev1" and "Topic/Dev2" respectively, then if your app subscribes to "Topic/#", it will receive messages for all sub-topics under "Topic"